# How to detect when a var is over a number and then changing a variable

Tags: java

I am making a monopoly game in java and I want a boolean variable to be set when a player passes GO. Here is my code:

```
int movetop1=Player1.space+roll();
Player1.space= movetop1>40 ? movetop1-40:movetop1;
```

I want to set a variable when the players space is reset.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
int movetop1=Player1.space+roll();
Boolean passingGo = moveTop1 > 40
Player1.space= passingGo ? movetop1-40:movetop1;
```

You already had the logic there, just had to add in a variable to catch it